# Is Samsung MZ-75E250B compatible with dell inspiron 5520

Tags: ssd, dell-inspiron

I have a 3 year old Dell Inspiron 5520 laptop. I was planning on getting a samsung SSD,

- [Samsung 850 EVO 250GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-75E250B/AM)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OAJ412U)

I tried to find if this SSD is compatible but all I found is [info on this page](http://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Dell-Inspiron-5520/2918).

Can someone here confirm that it is indeed compatible. If not I was going to get the Crucial equivalent model:

- [Crucial MX200 250GB SATA 2.5 Inch Internal Solid State Drive - CT250MX200SSD1](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct250mx200ssd1)

The Crucial web site indicates that this is indeed compatible with my laptop model.

Comment: Check the size of the current HDD that would determine if its capabilitiy or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be.

There's a few things I'd generally take into account

Firstly, whether there's an appropriate slot. A laptop may use 7mm or 9mm thick 2.5 inch drives (tho in some cases its plausible it could be purely msata or emmc). A 7mm drive would fit in the place of a 9mm drive but not vice versa. In this case its *definately* 2.5 inch sata and more likely to be 7mm thick rather than 9mm thick.

Since the crucial drive is compatible, the samsung should be. Most modern consumer SSDs are 7mm so they should be the same form factor

Electrically, both drives are sata III (and I believe the laptop in question is based off the Ivy Bridge platform) and so it should fit.

Only thing I'd get tripped up by is if dell chooses to attach a 'shim' between the drive and the connector on the desktop. If your old drive dosen't look like it has a sata connector, it may have a removable piece in front.

SATA drives are such common commodity parts these days that if the physical form factor matches, any one of them can be swapped for another model with no issues whatsoever

Comment: The current drive is mechanical.  So that rules out msata and emmc devices which neither of those devices are.  Best advice look, see the current dimionsions of the drive, and go off that :$

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to cover all the bases. Clarified

Comment: Thanks, I checked the dimensions and just went ahead with ordering the samsung. My ubuntu works like a charm on the SSD now. I couldn't migrate my windows 10 though, that is a whole another issue.